# RegExp web.config - Select path after / and rewrite as URL param

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a requirement to update the web.config file so that it replaces the path after the / and rewrites the URL as follows:

domain.com/acct01 -> domain.com/#/?id=acct01

domain.com/acct02 -> domain.com/#/?id=acct02

domain.com/acct03 -> domain.com/#/?id=acct03

...

Currently, for every account I am adding the following to the web.confg file. So for the above example I would need to do the following:

```
<rule name="acct01" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^acct01$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/#/?id=acct01" />
</rule>

<rule name="acct02" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^acct02$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/#/?id=acct02" />
</rule>

<rule name="acct03" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^acct03$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/#/?id=acct03" />
</rule>
```

As you can see, this can become unwieldy after many accounts. I'm looking for a general way of capturing the value of after the last / inside of the  URL and a more generalized way of replacing the URL in the action section after the id URL param. For example:

```
<rule name="addIDFromPath" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="[REGEX FOR GENERAL EXTRACTION OF PATH AFTER LAST /]" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/#/?id=[VALUE OF PATH EXTRACTED]" />
</rule>
```

If the URL contains a #, it should be ignored and left alone since this is an indication that it has been rewritten.

We are on a Windows Box with IIS installed so an alternative to the web.config file may be considered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood question correctly, but if the idea is to replace last `/` with `/#/?id=` then this pattern will do the work, replace

```
(?=\/([a-z0-9]+)$)
```

with `/#/?id=`.

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/kW8zU0/1

**EDIT**

Probably something like this:

```xml
<rule name="addIDFromPath" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(^|\/)([a-z0-9]+)(?=$)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/#/?id={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Not sure about group number, could be `{R:1}`

Pattern: `(^|\/)([a-z0-9]+)(?=$)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kW8zU0/4

Comment: That's great. The pattern does work but how do I use it in the web.config file so that the URL is rewritten?

Comment: In the web.config which you provided url already has the right ending: `#/?id=acct01`. What exactly you want to replace? Could you please provide some example of the file and expected output?

Comment: Looking at the snippet of the config file in the original question, the pattern to find would go in the <match url="^acct01$" /> and the replacement would go in the <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/#/?id=acct01" /> as the URL id parameter. I can potentially have 100s of these accounts and the snippet above replicated once for each account.

Comment: Thx. Would this ignore URLs with # so that domain.com/#/?id=acct03 is not mistakenly rewritten?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the demo I provided. It found only first three occurrences, but not last one. Let me know if it won't work.

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thanks man. web.config went from 1500 lines of code to 45!